# How to display li inline in the nav bar

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I am pretty new to HTML/CSS.

I want to display li in the nav inline but it won't work.

Here in my code. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#nav_bar .nav_button {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_bar">
      <li><a href="#">How we work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">View plans</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your CSS is trying to select a class `nav_button` that isn't in your HTML. Try `<li class="nav_button">` for each `<li>`.

Answer (score 3):

`inline` style need to be applied on the `li` element.

```css
#nav_bar li {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_bar">
    <li><a href="#">How we work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View plans</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave `inline` to `.nav_button` class, but never used it. Add the class where you want to use it.

```css
#nav_bar .nav_button {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_bar">
      <li class="nav_button"><a href="#">How we work</a></li>
      <li class="nav_button"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav_button"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li class="nav_button"><a href="#">View plans</a></li>
    </ul>
```